# How to make a reference to a functions with arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await, axios

I am trying to make a reference `ep` to a function that have arguments. So I have made the below PoC, to illustrate the problem I have run into.

The 3 functions inside `selectFunction()` all takes different arguments, and in the real world contain `axios` functions, so that is why I have `await`.

In the below I get `TypeError: ep is not a function`.

**Question**

Can someone figure out what is wrong?

```
(async () => {
  function getStatusCode(p) {console.log("hi")};
  function getString(p) {console.log("hi")};
  function getSecureString(p) {console.log("hi")};

  const p = {"type": 1, "string": 2, "host": 3};

  function selectFunction(p) {
    switch (p.type) {
      case 1:
      return getStatusCode({
        url: p.url
      });
      break
      case 2:
      return getString({
        string: p.string
      });
      break
      case 3:
      return getSecureString({
        hostname: p.host
      });
      break
      default:
      throw "error";
    };
  };
  // ep should be a function reference
  const ep = selectFunction(p);
  console.log(typeof ep);

  const isOk = await ep();
})();
```

Comment: You should compare your code with a Promise-based one, assuming you want to use `axios`, your functions will likely return a `Promise`, hence you would rather invoke them with `await ep` instead of `await ep()` (because they already are referencing a function). I think you might find this example useful (I slightly rewrote your example to get closer to a Promise-based approach): https://jsfiddle.net/zLtjmksq/

Comment: @briosheje This looks really interesting. Why does `typeof ep` say it is an ojbect and not a function?

Comment: Looks like you want either `const ep = selectFunction; await ep(p);` or `const ep = () => selectFunction(p); await ep();`. Not sure why you expect `selectFunction(p)` to return a function reference.

Comment: check out [Function#bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#partially_applied_functions) or the general topic [tag:partial-application]

Comment: @SandraSchlichting because the functions are returning a `Promise` which is, in fact, an `object` (which is awaitable). If you want to work with axios, you can follow either of these approaches: 1) have a function returning a Promise (like my example). 2) Have a function returning a function that returns a promise.  Using the second approach, you will end up invoking with `await ep()`, while in the first case you will end up invoking with `ep` instead. If you want to, I can provide you an example without async-await that will likely help you understand how async-await works under the hood

Comment: @SandraSchlichting perhaps this might help you understand: https://jsfiddle.net/6nya950b/ I've added the approach without async-await just above the async-await. If you look at what `ep` is, you will probably understand that `ep` is not meant to be a function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise (about promises in general)

Answer (score 3):

You’re returning the *result* of calling the function, not a function itself.

If you need to do this, you might find success in explicitly returning a function reference by wrapping your calls in `selectFunction` as anonymous functions:

```
function selectFunction(p) {
  switch (p.type) {
    case 1:
      return function(arg) {
        return getStatusCode({
          url: arg.url
        })
      };
    case 2:
      return function(arg) {
        return getString({
          string: arg.string
        })
      };
    case 3:
      return function(arg) {
        return getSecureString({
          hostname: arg.host
        })
      };
    default:
      throw "error";
  };
};
```

Comment: I can't get it to compile. Can you take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/3L1dkmrw/ ?

Comment: I think your @Bergi's edits should address why it wouldn't compile (I forgot the `return` keyword in the inner function). Thanks for the assists - was on mobile when initially providing the answer.

Comment: I still can't compile it. https://jsfiddle.net/d7zsw1x9/

Comment: @SandraSchlichting Really? The snippet you linked runs fine for me (logs `function`). What about it isn't working? Nothing jumping out at me at the moment.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting On second pass, you're not providing an argument to the returned function. When calling `ep` on line 36 in the linked jsFiddle, you'd need to provide `p` (or another conformant object) as your argument: `const isOk = await ep(p);`

Answer (score 1):

`const ep = selectFunction(p)` is setting `ep` to the value returned by `selectFunction` given `p` as an argument.

If you want to later use `ep(p)` and expect it to act like `selectFunction(p)`, this should work:

`const ep = p => selectFunction(p);`

It is a [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

It does not execute `selectFunction`, but refers to it.

Answer (score 0):

The below code have the advantage that `selectFunction()` is only run once.

```
const delay = require('delay');

(async () => {
  function getStatusCode(p) {console.log("hi1")};
  function getString(p) {console.log("hi2")};
  function getSecureString(p) {console.log("hi3")};

  const p = {"type": 3, "string": 2, "host": 3};

  function selectFunction(p) {
    console.log("only run once");
    switch (p.type) {
      case 1:
      return getStatusCode;
      break
      case 2:
      return getString;
      break
      case 3:
      return getSecureString;
      break
      default:
      throw "error";
    };
  };
  // ep should be a function reference
  const ep = selectFunction(p);
  console.log(typeof ep);

  while (true) {
    const isOk = await ep();
    await delay(1000);
  };
})();
```

Comment: What is the `while(true)` and `delay` purpose? that's unnecessary.